# socket.io with http request

Tags: node.js, http, socket.io

In my app I use socket.io app with express like following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

http.listen(3000, function () {console.log('*** listening on *:3000');});

io.on('connection', function(socket) { console.log('User is connected'); });

// express route
var router = express.Router();
router.route('download').get(function (req, res) {
                fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(res);
            });
app.use('/api', router);
```

After using http request to download file the socket.io connection is disconnected (ping timeout) and then reconnect.

Is there a problem to use http request if I have a socket connected using socket.io.

Note: when file is small the socket is always connected.

Comment: I guess you need to make the server listen after adding all routes.

Comment: I listen after adding routes but same problem